# Angular 2 ContentChild is undefined

Tags: angular

I am trying to get the ElementRef of an element on which I have added a custom attribute using a Directive as a ContentChild of a component but I get undefined when I log it after the content has been initialized. Could you please tell me why?

TestComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test-component',

  template: `
    <h1>Test Component</h1>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `
})
export class TestComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChild(TestDirective) child;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.child);
  }
}
```

TestDirective:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[test-directive]'
})
export class TestDirective {
}
```

AppComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  declarations: ['TestComponent'],
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <test-component>
      <h2 test-directive>Test Directive</h2>
    </test-component>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Hello123!';
}
```

Please refer to think Plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/9KUnFWjVIbYidUtF2Avf?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the `declaration` of your `TestDirective`!

See your updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/x5rLcvJnRhnVxM7fgvvK?p=preview

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';
import { TestDirective } from './test.directive';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent,
    TestDirective
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```