# Angular's @ContentChild is not working for me

Tags: angular

Trying to understand Angular2 but somehow @ContentChild is not working. There must be very basic mistake from my end but I can't figure it out, where. Any help would be much appreciated.

app.components.ts

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <p #boundContent>{{localCounter}}</p>
    Verify me: <p>{{boundContent.textContent}}</p>
      <hr>
      <fa-contentchild></fa-contentchild>
            `,
  styles: [`
      h1{color:red;}
  `]
})
export class AppComponent {
  localCounter:number =700;
  doShow:boolean=false;
  title = 'angular sucks!';
}
```

contentchild.component.ts

```ts
import { AfterContentInit, Component, ContentChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'fa-contentchild',
  template: `
    <p>I am from content Child: {{boundContent}}</p>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class ContentchildComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  @ContentChild('boundContent')
  boundContent:HTMLElement;

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.boundContent);
  }

}
```

Comment: In the console, it always remain undefined.

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598072/angular-2-contentchild-is-undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `@ContentChild()` you can only query for content not for siblings

This way it will work

```ts
  template: `

    Verify me: <p>{{boundContent.textContent}}</p>
      <hr>
      <fa-contentchild>
        <p #boundContent>{{localCounter}}</p>
      </fa-contentchild>
            `,
```

An alternative way would be

```ts
  template: `
    <p #boundContent>{{localCounter}}</p>
    Verify me: <p>{{boundContent.textContent}}</p>
      <hr>
      <fa-contentchild [content]="boundContent"></fa-contentchild>
            `,
```

```ts
export class ContentchildComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  @Input()
  boundContent:HTMLElement;

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.boundContent);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I easily used @Input() meta-data/tag and got results. I wanted to play with @ContentChild() to get data

Comment: Got it. Much appreciated.